HP ProLiant Server no longer starts - red LED flashing + iLO error
I'm having a problem with my HP ProLiant server (model ML350e Gen8) which refuses to start. Here are the details:
Symptoms:

When I turn on the server, the fans start up briefly, then everything
shuts down.
A red LED flashes on the front panel.
Via the iLO interface, I get the following error code: System Power Fault Detected (XR: 24 00 MID: ...)

What I tested:
Minimum configuration:

Removed all non-essential peripherals (PCIe cards, hard disks, etc.).
Kept only: CPU, 1 RAM module and power supply connected to motherboard.
Problem persists.

CMOS reset:

Removed CMOS battery and applied reset procedure (activated Switch S6).
Also tested the DIP switch sequence (#1, #5, #6) described in the documentation.
No change observed.

LED on motherboard:

The CR8 LED on the motherboard is flashing, indicating a potential problem.

Additional information:

iLO remains functional, allowing me to retrieve error logs.
The server worked perfectly before being stored for a few days in a clean environment. No shocks or rough handling to report.

Have you ever encountered this kind of problem? Any help or suggestions are welcome, as I'm running out of ideas.
Thank you very much for your support!

Likely the PSU's had it. Long out of support, I guess.

Yes, it does look like a PS issue.

Power supply failure.
iLO runs off the 5Vsb, so it remains active even when the main power is off. At power up it checks for reasonable values on teh 12V, 5V, and 3.3V lines (if there are any in that model) and shuts things back down if any of them are out of spec.
At a guess, caps in the main supply dried out and failed. They were all right as long as the system was running, but the strain of the restart was too much for them to handle.
